# SCSS @import with & to children to class

Tags: sass

I know you can do an import inside a class like this:

```
.my-class
{
    @import "another-file.scss";
}
```

Such that a class `.foo` in `another-file.scss` will compile to `.my-class .foo` in the output.

What I want to do is import a file such that all the rules in the file get a certain class added to them, like this:

```
.my-class
{
    &@import "another-file.scss";
}
```

Such that `.foo` in `another-file.scss` will compile to `.my-class.foo` in the output.

I'm building a set of components that all share a class because they are all part of the same "kit", and I want them all to share a class that denotes them as such, but I don't want to have them all in the same file under one giant nest.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you just need to preface the selectors in the file you are importing with `&`.

For example, if you were to import the following file, it would create rules for `.my-class.header`, `my-class.header.cool` and `my-class.footer`:

```
&.header {
    color: blue;
    &.cool {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

&.footer {
    color: blue;
}
```